# Блок с закруглениями?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Надо чтобы был такой div как на картинке. Пробовал через border-radius: 0% 0% 50% 50% / 0% 0% 40% 40%; Но там получаются нижние края загнутые, а надо как на картинке[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что если то что у Вас получается поместить в `<div style="position:parent">`, присвоить ему абсолютное позиционирование и сделать шире чем родительский блок и установить `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: Можешь показать это в коде?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Вот так**

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background: red;
  -webkit-clip-path: ellipse(75% 47% at 52% 25%);
  clip-path: ellipse(75% 47% at 52% 25%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Comment: @Geyan, ваш код не кроссбраузерный. Пример не работает как минимум в firefox, ie, edge.

Comment: mJeevas одно 100% кроссбраузерное решение показали чуть ниже с одним голосом и автор ответа Umer , вот это решение очень хорошее , ног ТС посчитал мой ответ как решение , я не причём , вот 100% правильное решение http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/oLRPdZ?editors=110  но могу и на svg нарисовать

Answer (score 6):

Думаю вы так имели ввиду?:)

```css
#main::before{
    background-color: white;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -5;
    top: 50%;
    left: -20%;
    width: 180%;
    height: 100%;  
}
#main::after{
    background-color: #FFC107;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;       
    left: -20%;;
    width: 140%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 80%;
}
#main{
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 width: 50%;
 height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
 background: #ffc107;
 transform: translateX(-50%)translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать жёлтый блок побольше, чтобы `border-radius` превратился в "свисающее брюшко"

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 150%;  
  margin-left: -25%;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: ваш код не работает